# Samba Client (smbclient) always writes to standard error when getting files

Tags: linux, networking, share, samba, smb

I am getting some files via an smb client (I use version 4.13.14-Ubuntu) command:

```
smbclient //<myip>/<myshare> -c "prompt;cd myPath; mget *.csv;" -U <myuser> 2> logs.txt
```

This command results in the text file containing

```
getting file \myPath\dde_DC-Machine-99999901-DeviceId_20210624.csv of size 3710 as dde_DC-Machine-99999901-DeviceId_20210624.csv (13.6 KiloBytes/sec) (average 13.6 KiloBytes/sec)
```

Which shows the file has been successfully downloaded (which is actually the case, the file is completely available after executing the command).

However, as you see from the standard error redirection "2>", the logs on success are written to stderr where I would expect them on stdout.

Now when I add some invalid parameters like a non existing path

```
smbclient //<myip>/<myshare> -c "prompt;cd nonExistingPath; mget *.csv;" -U <myuser> 2> logs.txt
```

The terminal prints NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND which is correct but coming from the **standard out** whereas the standard error is empty.

It almost looks like the client writes to the stdout if an error occurs and to the stderr if everything works fine, so exactly the wrong way around. Beware this happens only when using the mget or get commands, other commands I've tested seem to work as they should.

**Question**

Is there a bug in the smbclient, or a misunderstanding from my side?

Comment: Writing to stdout instead of stderr is not really that much of a bug...

Comment: but the problem is vice versa, it writes to stderr on success and to stdout on failure as you see in my examples

Comment: That is fine - stderr is typical logging stream, for logs, like something succeeded. And also not that much of a bug, some utilities just do that.

Comment: Might be the case for other tools, but the smb client docs clearly state that it should log to teh stdout per default, except the -E flag is passed: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbclient.1.html
(see -E flag description)
Plus, it DOES log the to the sdout if there is an error (so the wrong way around)

Comment: Yea I am noticing this too. Annoying but I'll just check both stdout and stderror.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Samba config file (/usr/local/samba/lib/smb.conf) contains the '-E'.

"-E  Sends output from commands to stderr instead of stdout."

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/appc.html

Comment: It doesn't contain "-E". For other commands like "ls" the logs are send to sdtout, but for mget (and get) its vice versa..